# Creating own datepicker in Angular4 application

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am creating my own datepicker and I'm struggling with a problem.
I have a function named toggleShowCalendar() and I call it when user clicks an calendar icon. This function makes a div visible on the page.

The problem appears when user wants to close the datepicker. User has to click the calendar icon again, what is a little bit confusing.

```
<img src="calendar.jpg" (click)="toggleShowCalendar()"/>    
<div *ngIf="calendarVisible" class="calendar">Here is my own calendar</div>

  toggleShowCalendar() {
      this.calendarVisible= !this.calendarVisible;
  }
```

How to allow to click anywhere outside the div, to close datepicker?

Comment: You need to find a place to put function 'fn' in your angular for document.body.addEventListener('click', **fn**, true);

Comment: The above code registers a click event for anywhere in the page

Comment: https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/angular-2-a-simple-click-outside-directive/

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```js
// in the component class
displayDiv = false;

// in the component's constructor
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (this.displayDiv) {
    this.displayDiv = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div [hidden]="!displayDiv">
  Div content here
</div>
```